# How to spawn a server in Flutter / dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm looking to try an replicate an Artemis like game, where you have several devices as clients, and one of the devices acts as the server for all the game logic.  I found a socket.io dart port I can use for client and server, but how to I spawn a tread to run the server instance in Flutter?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You do not need a thread for that. If you think you must, look for Dart and Isolate (there is an `isolate` package on pub that is convenient) but again, usually no need because Dart is async and can process work async

Comment: I worry that since single theaded that the server could take a while to process stuff, and slow down the GUI for the person who is also hosting.  An Isolate seems exactly what I want. Thanks so much! :)